# Stack in python with O(1) time complexity

Tags: python-3.x, list, stack

I'm trying to write a code in python that imitates a stack, it has 3 properties:

- push(x): append x to the end of the list
- pop: pops rightmost value and return it
- increase(k): increases the top k elements of list by 1, meaning if the list is [1,2,3] with a k value of 2; the updated list is [1,3,4].

I was able to do this easily, but i'm required to do it with a O(1) time complexity, here is my code:

```
from collections import deque



class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []
        self.new = []

    def push(self, x):
        self.s.append(x)
        self.new.append(0)

    def pop(self):
        return self.new.pop() + self.s.pop()

    def increase(self, k):
        b = self.new[-k:]
        a = [1] * k
        self.new = self.new[0:-k]
        self.new += map(sum, zip(a,b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Stack()
    s.push(1)
    s.push(2)
    s.push(3)
    s.increase(2)
    print(s.pop()) # 4
    s.push(1)
    s.increase(2)
    print(s.pop()) # 2
    print(s.pop()) # 4
    print(s.pop()) # 1
```

The list itself does not have to change, but these are the desired answers when calling the pop() function. Meaning only the illusion of the list being manipulated is enough.

[image: The error I get from this code:]

Edit:
I found the fastest way to do this, here is the code:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []
        self.new = [0]

    def push(self, x):
        self.s.append(x)
        self.new.append(0)

    def pop(self):
        self.new[-2] += self.new[-1]
        return self.new.pop() + self.s.pop()

    def increase(self, k):
        self.new[-1] += 1
        self.new[-1-k] -= 1
```

Comment: stack is LIFO, so `pop` should extract/return the rightmost item

Comment: k is not O(1) so you cannot go and do something k-times. After an increase you can insert more elements that should be unaffected so you would have to put some marker elements into the list to track the pending increases and apply those at pop. You cannot merge increases for a different number of elements. If you ask for N increases with different k, pop would be O(N). Nope, if there is a solution with those constraints, I don't see it.

Comment: The idea here is not to actually edit the list, but to give the user an illusion that the list is being modified in those ways, and return the correct values when calling the pop function. This course is one of my university's most difficult, and the book says there is some way. I'v tried almost everything I could haha

Comment: I'v tried importing deque, but I can't seen to slice the deque in order to increase

Comment: Is the O(1) time complexity worst-case or amortized over some sequence of operations?

Comment: I get this error: Test failed when given the following input:

s = Stack()
for i in range(5*10**4):
 s.push(i+1)
for i in range(5*10**4 - 1):
 s.increase(5*10**4)
print(s.pop())

Your code used too much time for processing the input.   Apparently this is the worst case that it is supposed to be able to handle.

Comment: If you track increases as some kind of element, increases with the same k could be merged. So the element needs to track how many and by how much.

Comment: Could you perhaps show me this idea in code?

Comment: I don't actually speak python. Merely here for the algorithm stuff.